# Select next first element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
        <fieldset id="fs1">
            <legend id="leg1">First Legend</legend>
            <div id="div1">
                "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
                laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi                   
                 <div id="div1Child">
                      ********* Sample text here ****************
                  </div>
            </div>
           
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="fs2">
            <legend id="leg2">Second Legend</legend>
            <div id="div2">
                "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
                voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint
               
                  <div id="div2Child">
                       
                      ********* Sample text here ****************
                 </div>
            </div>
           
        </fieldset>
```

When I click the ***legend***, I should get the contents of the first div (div1 and div2) only. I don't want to display the "Sample Text Here" which is the child div (Id -->> div1Child and div2Child) of the div.

Comment: I updated my code showing how you can handle showing the divChild if the user wants to "read more" or "see more".  The click on the legend will only show the first DIV and then hide all children DIV's within that parent.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code on how you can handle showing the first parent div on legend click, and then showing the child div of the parent div with clicking a button "read more"...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("fieldset legend").click(function() {
            $(this).next("div").toggle().children("div").each(function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
        $(".btnreadmore").click(function() {
            $(this).next("div").show();
        });
    });
</script>

<fieldset id="fs1">
        <legend id="leg1">First Legend</legend>
        <div id="div1" class="hidden">
            "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
            laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi. 
            <input type="button" value="read more" class="btnreadmore" />                  
             <div id="div1Child">
                  ********* Sample text here ****************
              </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset id="fs2">
        <legend id="leg2">Second Legend</legend>
        <div id="div2" class="hidden">
            "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium
            voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint
            <input type="button" value="read more" class="btnreadmore" />                  
              <div id="div2Child">
                  ********* Sample text here ****************
             </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Yeah, I use this code already. But I don't want to allow other div's inside to toggle().

Comment: Yeah, as per your code, it will hide all the divs inside "div1". But when div1Child is clicked, I shouldn't allow them to toggle(). I'm trying to write a common method for whole application. Any idea?

Comment: No no. toggle() only fires when legend is clicked.

Comment: @engineerachu: Your question says you want to toggle the first DIV for the legend on click.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can think of..

```
$('legend').click(function(e){
     var $div = $(this).next('div').clone();
     var text = $div.children().remove().end().text();
     console.log(text);
});
```

**EDIT:** The above code assumes that:

1. you don't want anything inside your
   `<div id="div1">` except the immediate
   text, and
2. that you're using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to develop your code.

Comment: Hello dalbaeb,

         You are absolutely correct. I get the text of the first div only. Now my exact scenario is to toggle the css->display to "block" and "none" when clicking of the div. When I click on "div1", all contents should toggle the display css (block and none), but when I click on "div1Child", it shouldn't happen. You have any idea? I tried as you said, but it doesn't seem to accept the css property.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. This completely changes the task. What are you clicking on, and what do you want to hide/show? If you want the text in div#div1 to be hidden when you click within div#div1 then you should consider wrapping the text in a span or something, and toggle that span.

Comment: Okay, I'll make it clear. From the above html sample, when I click on "div1", all the contents will toggle(). When I click on "div1Child", that div should not toggle. I'm trying to write a common method to work all over the application.

Comment: 1: You should edit the question. 2: Wrap the content you want to toggle into a span, and toggle it instead of the whole DIV (assuming you have control over HTML markup). Otherwise I really don't know what you're going to click on after having hid the entire DIV once.

Answer (score 0):

$("leg1").next() and $("leg2").next() ?

See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("fieldset > div:first-child")
```